# Perl pattern match and substitute to replace only 4th word and retain everything else

Tags: regular-expression, perl, replace

I need to replace the 4th word on every line with `0`:

Original:

```
R5_427 MMP15@2:S VDD:1 967.796 TC1=0.0004785156
R5_428 MMP15@2:S lninst_M55:S 0.001
```

Expected output:

```
R5_427 MMP15@2:S VDD:1 0 TC1=0.0004785156
R5_428 MMP15@2:S lninst_M55:S 0
```

I have tried to write a piece of code to do this, but it doesn't work as it seems to add a `0` as well as `967.796` in the 1st test case.
I'm looking for a generic solution not depending on the exact number of words after the 3rd word.

My attempt:

```
while(<RD>)
{
    my $line;
    $line = $_;
    chop $line; 
    if ($line =~ /^R(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*$)/) {
        my $mod_line = "R$1 $2 $3 0 $4";
        print WR "$mod_line\n";
    }
    else {
        print WR "$line\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain (in words, not code) what you are trying to do. It looks like you are trying to set something to 0. If so, tell us what. How can we identify the part you want to set to 0?

Comment: Topic subject captures that right?
"Perl pattern match and substitute to replace only 4th word and retain everything else"

Comment: Make use of Perl's `split` and `join` functions, along with `perl -cw`.

Comment: Since these `spf` files are huge and depending on how deep the hierarchy is, there is every possibility that the lines spill onto the next by means of a `+` so you need to factor in the fact that the fourth field can be on next or succeeding line. Since you are essentially shorting the interconnect resistors, why don't you extract a Conly netlist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Perl, you could do:

```perl
 #!/usr/bin/env perl

while (<>) {
  ## split the line into fileds on whitespace
  my @fields = split(/\s+/);
  ## set the 4th field (numbering starts at 0) to "0" if
  ## this line starts with an R (since that's what you had originally)
  $fields[3] = 0 if /^R/;
  ## join thew fields with a space and print
  print join(" ", @fields) . "\n";
}
```

If you run the above on your example, you get:

```
$ foo.pl file 
R5_427 MMP15@2:S VDD:1 0 TC1=0.0004785156
R5_428 MMP15@2:S lninst_M55:S 0
```

Or, if you want to keep your original logic with the more complex regular expression, you could do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
open(my $RD, '<', $ARGV[0]);
while(<$RD>)
{
  ## you want chomp, not chop. chomp only removes trailing newlines
  ## while chop removes the last character no matter what it is.
  ## You also don't need the $line variable, perl will default to $_
  chomp;
  ## You don't need to capture every group, only the
  ## ones you will use later. Also, to allow for only
  ## three fields, you need '\s*.*' and not '\s+.*'
  if (/^(R\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+)\s+\S+(\s*.*)/) {
    ## No need for a temp variable, just print
    print "$1 0 $2\n";
  }
  else {
    print "$_\n";
  }
}
```

Of course, you don't really need a script for this, you can just write a one-liner:

```
$ perl -lane '$F[3] = 0 if /^R/; print join(" ", @F)' file 
R5_427 MMP15@2:S VDD:1 0 TC1=0.0004785156
R5_428 MMP15@2:S lninst_M55:S 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nicely explanatory response @terdon. What's the "-lane" option for perl in the last technique?

Comment: @Pratap the `-l` means "remove trailing newlines and add a newline to every `print` call"., the `-a` automatically splits each input line on whitespace into the `@F` array, the `-n` means "read the input file line by line and apply the script to each line" and the `-e` gives the actual script. See `man perlrun`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to skip the first 3 fields and replace the 4th with a 0.0 only for resistors.

```
$ perl -pe 's/^R(?:\S+\s+){3}\K\S+/0.0/' file
R5_427 MMP15@2:S VDD:1 0.0 TC1=0.0004785156
R5_428 MMP15@2:S lninst_M55:S 0.0
```